# popup calendar by clicking on image: django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

i wanna have a textbox in my web page with an image next to it. when user clicks on image, it shows the calander that help user choose the date (popup calendar). i've done it in raw html. but now i wanna use django forms(although i don't have any models) so i searched and found out that i have to write my own widget in forms.py. s.th like:

```
class CalendarWidget(forms.TextInput):
        css = ('/media/css/main.css', '/media/css/js-cal.css')
        js = ('/media/js/js-cal.min.js')
```

i have a class `backupForm` in `forms.py` which contains all form fields.

my question is: **to use the above `CalendarWidget`, should i define a field in `backupForm` class like this?**:

```
date1 = forms.CharField(widget=CalendarWidget)
```

how can i bind an image to this textbox and force user that only input his date from this calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the form field of the input field(textbox) and apply `CalendatWidget` as the widget of the field. The widget takes the responsibility of creating/binding the image which works as a button.

Django Admin use a `AdminDateWidget` on form field of `model.DateField` automatically, despite the modelform part, you could check it in `django/contrib/admin/widgets.py`. Check `init()` function inside `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js` to know how does Django create/bind the calendar button to one input field.

You could even use `AdminDateWidget` in a front page, as long as the page loads required CSS/JS resources and has certain attribute set....

Comment: thanks, but what do you mean by "The widget takes the responsibility of creating/binding the image which works as a button."? i can't understand how i can bind an image to textbox. what should i do with/after this line of code?

Comment: @user1597122 Take the built-in `DateTimeShortcuts.js` for example, it is invoked w/ the input (textbox in your words) and dynamically creates an `<img>` tag which reacts to mouse click event, renders calendar and fills the selected value back to the input, all is done in javascript, refs [the code here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js#L53)